# Better way to check if something is nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to parse a XML file using `TBXML`.  However, this parser has no error-checking built in so if an element doesn't exist it crashes.  Here's how I'm parsing one of my XML files:

```
TBXML *XML = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData:myxmlfile] retain];
if (XML.rootXMLElement) {
    TBXMLElement *XMLRoot = XML.rootXMLElement;
    if ([TBXML childElementNamed:@"blah" parentElement:XMLRoot]) {
        TBXMLElement *Blah = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"blah" parentElement:XMLRoot];   
        if ([TBXML childElementNamed:@"stuff" parentElement:Blah]) {
            TBXMLElement *Item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:Blah;
            if ([TBXML childElementNamed:@"stuff:blah" parentElement:Item]) {
                TBXMLElement *something = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"stuff:blah" parentElement:Item];
                NSString *Something = [TBXML textForElement:something];
                //do something here...
            }
            else {
               [self showFetchError];
                [XML release];
                return;}
        } else {
            [self showFetchError];
            [XML release];
            return;}
    } else {
        [self showFetchError];
        [XML release];
        return;}
} else {
    [self showFetchError];
    [XML release];
    return;
}
```

As you can see, it's making a call twice for each item.  That seems like a huge waste of overhead to me.  Any way I can do the same verification of each item without doing what I'm doing right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a shorter version:

```
BOOL success = NO;
TBXML *XML = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData:myxmlfile] retain];
if (XML.rootXMLElement) {
    TBXMLElement *XMLRoot = XML.rootXMLElement;
    if ([TBXML childElementNamed:@"blah" parentElement:XMLRoot]) {
        TBXMLElement *Blah = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"blah" parentElement:XMLRoot];   
        if ([TBXML childElementNamed:@"stuff" parentElement:Blah]) {
            TBXMLElement *Item = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"item" parentElement:Blah;
            if ([TBXML childElementNamed:@"stuff:blah" parentElement:Item]) {
                success = YES;
                TBXMLElement *something = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"stuff:blah" parentElement:Item];
                NSString *Something = [TBXML textForElement:something];
                //do something here...
            }
        }
    }
}

if (!success) {
    [self showFetchError];
    [XML release];
    return;
}
```

Updated version using enumerator:

```
TBXML *XML = [[TBXML tbxmlWithXMLData:myxmlfile] retain];
NSArray *path = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blah", @"item", @"stuff:blah", nil];
NSEnumerator *e = [path objectEnumerator];
TBXMLElement *currentNode = XML.rootXMLElement;
BOOL success = NO;
while ((NSString *node = [e nextObject]) && currentNode) {
    if ([node isEqualToString:[path lastObject]]) {
        success = YES;
        NSString *Something = [TBXML textForElement:currentNode];
        // do the last element thing with string
    } else {
        currentNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:node parentElement:currentNode];
    }
}

if (!success) {
    [self showFetchError];
    [XML release];
    return;
}
```

I'm not sure if enumerator version works, but off top of my head it should solve your problem.

Comment: Well, that looks better but it still doesn't solve the problem of the double-calls to parse the element.

Comment: Did a lot of updates since was in a hurry with this solution. Now it should even compile!

Comment: Would you say that using the enumerator would make it faster, or not?

Comment: Not sure. But using fast enumeration instead of enumerator would be faster (although code should be rewritten a bit as well).

Comment: I accepted Daniel's answer because it reduced the number of calls for the different elements like I was hoping.  However, thank you for taking the time to create your enumerating code.  I'm sure it will come in handy some day for me. :)

Comment: The enumerating code did reduce the calls for fetching child nodes as well. You should've figured .)P

Answer (score 1):

You can do things like:

```
TBXMLElement *Blah = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"blah" parentElement:XMLRoot];
if (Blah) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah that's more of what I was looking for.  I'll try both answers and will accept the one that works faster. :)

Comment: You can, of course, combine both techniques.  Eimantas' answer makes the code shorter, but shouldn't affect runtime performance (the enumerator will actually add a little bit of overhead); my answer will make it run faster.  But unless this piece of code gets called _extremely_ frequently, I doubt you will see any practical performance improvement.